# How to access the initial point of a Pan Gesture in it's .Ended state

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer, cgpoint

I am trying to implement a Pan Gesture in my app where I need to access the initial point in the .Ended state.

Here is the code.

```
func handleTestViewTap (panRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

    var locationOfBeganTap: CGPoint?

    if panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {           
        locationOfBeganTap = panRecognizer.locationInView(view)
        print("locationOfBeganTap in BEGAN State -> .\(locationOfBeganTap)")

    } else if panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {            
        print("locationOfBeganTap -> .\(locationOfBeganTap)")
        print("locationOfBeganTap in ENDED State -> .\(locationOfBeganTap)")

    }     
}
```

Now, here is the output:

```
locationOfBeganTap in BEGAN State -> .Optional((195.5, 120.0))
locationOfBeganTap in ENDED State -> .nil
```

I am unable to understand why the `locationOfBeganTap` is `nil` in the `.Ended` state

Can someone please share the code to access `locationOfBeganTap` in `.Ended` state...

Comment: Could you try storing the location in a variable?

Comment: Am I not doing that already?
I am storing the location in `locationOfBeganTap`, isn't it?

Comment: @JF Please share the code

Comment: Yes, but in a local function storage, everytime that the function is executed, the variable is created, and when it finishes, the storage gets removed. You need to create the variable in the controller.

Comment: @Sealos Hey, thanks a lot for that simple fix, it works like a charm now. All I had to do was move just one line of code i.e. `var locationOfBeganTap: CGPoint?` to `viewDidLoad()` function
Thanks a lot, you are my saviour

Comment: curious. Why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing this doesn’t work. Instead, calculate it all at the end:

```
func handleTestViewTap (panRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

    if panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {            
        print("locationOfBeganTap -> (.\(touch.locationInView(view).x - touch.translationInView(view).x), .\(touch.locationInView(view).y - touch.translationInView(view).y))")
        print("location in ENDED State -> .\(touch.locationInView(view))")
    }     
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that code. It works for me. However, I prefer the other method i.e. to define the `CGPoint` in the `viewDidLoad()`. Your's is just another way of doing it.

Comment: @EcoApps How come?

Comment: Just because, you need to recalculate the initial point in your method. Which is not needed in other method

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `locationOfBeganTap` to be an instance variable instead of a local variable.

```
class WhatEverClassThisIs {
    var locationOfBeganTap: CGPoint?

    // and the rest of your stuff

    func handleTestViewTap (panRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        if panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {           
            locationOfBeganTap = panRecognizer.locationInView(view)
            print("locationOfBeganTap in BEGAN State -> .\(locationOfBeganTap)")
        } else if panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {            
            print("locationOfBeganTap -> .\(locationOfBeganTap)")
            print("locationOfBeganTap in ENDED State -> .\(locationOfBeganTap)")
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is what I tried 

`class initialTouchPanGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer {
    var initialTouchLocation: CGPoint!
    
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
        initialTouchLocation = touches.first!.locationInView(view)
        print("Pan Gesture BEGAN")
        print("initialTouchLocation -> .\(initialTouchLocation)")
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {       
        print("Pan Gesture ENDED")
    }
}`

Comment: How do you not understand? It's exactly your code with one tiny change. I moved the variable from outside the method to the class. And please don't post a bunch of code in comments. If needed, add an update to your question. But why did you make such a radical change? Now you are overriding `touchesBegan|End` instead of using the pan gesture.

Comment: Now, I get it. You were trying to explain me what @Sealos told in above comments. I got confused as I tried this radical method based on some other posts. Sorry for the confusion. My issue is now resolved.
Thanks a lot for your help.